# How can I use a secondary axis in Numbers?

Tags: numbers, graph

One of my main problems with Numbers is the fact that it has much less of the functionality of Excel. That's why I barely use Numbers.

One of the main things that I always thought impossible was plotting two axes on one graph. This is my main reason for my dislike of Numbers.

Now that many other interesting questions that I didn't think had answers are getting answered, I thought I might ask this question:

How can I plot two lines on one graph using a secondary axis in Numbers?

Comment: I think the accepted answer for this should now be changed as this is now possible.

Answer (score 13):

If you want a line graph with 2 y-axes. You to insert->Chart-> 2-Axis. Put in your data. One of the sets will be a line the others a bar. The way to fix that is: Select the one that is a bar then to go to the Inspector-> Chart-> Series. It will say series type-> select that and change it from bar to line. Right below that it says plot on: There you can determine if you want that line to be plotted on y(1) or y(2).

[image: What it looks like at first for 2-axis]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "2D 2-Axis" is the chart type in Numbers 3.2.

Comment: Yes, a welcome improvement in Number 3 from Numbers 2!

Comment: Alas, it's not an x-y plot but a categorical chart. So if you have many or unevenly spaced x values, it will look wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Yes `Numbers` does now supports two axes. Steps are:

1. Select the chart, change the type to **2D 2-Axis**
2. Make sure you have more than one data series selected.
3. The **Series** tab for each data series will allow you select which axis to use for each series and the type: columns, lines or areas.
4. The chart **Axis** tab contains (Y1) and (Y2) tabs which you can customise.

If you are familiar with customising graphs in `Numbers` - it isn't complicated.

Comment: Thank you! This chart took me forever to find. I thought I was crazy until I read and re-read the list of chart types that I could create from the drop down menu. The picture charts all seem to be single axis.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Numbers' only solution is the **2D 2-axis** graph which has *categorical* x-axis values. If you want to retain a *numerical* x-axis, the best way I've found is actually to lay two graphs over the top of each other.

**Step 1**

Create two separate graphs of the same size and the same x-axis extents. Style them as you wish, but only add grid lines, axis lines and x-axis labels to one of them.

[image: two separate graphs]

**Step 2**

This is the worst bit. Because the y-axis [cannot be moved](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4972609), use control-command-shift-4 to copy a screenshot of the secondary y-axis to the clipboard. Paste with command-v. Make sure the "Zoom" level in Numbers is set to 100%, otherwise the pasted image will need to be resized.

**Step 3**

Turn off the axis labels on the secondary y-axis, then lay the graphs over the top of each other, using the alignment guides that pop up to align the axes. Position the copy of the secondary y-axis labels. Voilà

[image: combined graph]

Comment: Good answer, but it really REALLY shouldn't be necessary to go to such ridiculous lengths just to do a simple scatter plot with two different Y axis scales (not category X axis). It's hardly an esoteric requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do the same thing in Numbers 2009 (v2.1), but had to fiddle a lot.
Use the 2-axis format. The program resists you all the way.

Here is a 2-axis graph (climate diagram) created using Numbers 2.1:

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps expand your answer with specific instructions as to how the graph in the screenshot was created?

Comment: "The program resists you all the way through": yup, that pretty much sums up my experience with Numbers charts too. Shame, because it makes an otherwise good program borderline unusable.